Is a expression "just like you don't " idiomatic?
A: Do you know what this phrase means?
B: Well, I don't know the exact meaning  just like you don't, but...
Is the bold part idiomatic?

I wouldn’t quite call it wrong, but it’s not idiomatic—in American English anyway. The awkwardness arises from an apparent inconsistency in its sense (polarity, direction, arithmetic sign). Just like compares in a way that highlights similarities—and its complement is implicitly expected to be expressed affirmatively. So

I do understand its meaning, just like you do

is fine. But just like you don’t creates the impression that there’s an inversion of the comparison, even though the intention is to highlight a similarity and not a contrast.
So

I am stumped by its exact meaning, just like you are

is fine. Another option is to avoid the just like entirely by going with something like

I don’t understand the exact meaning any more than you do.


Yes. The words I have enclosed in square brackets are implied, and this is understood by native or fluent speakers: I don't know the exact meaning just like you don't [understand the exact meaning].
I don't like shellfish/believe in God/want to live in Japan/have any pets [just as you don't].
This type of omission is called ellipsis. Ellipsis in linguistics refers to the omission (removal) of one or more words from a clause. The rest of the sentence can be understood through context, so the omitted words are not necessary to the meaning of the sentence. Using ellipsis often reduces the need for repetition, as any unnecessary words can just be left out.
Note that 'ellipsis' is also the name of a type of punctuation consisting of (usually) three dots (sometimes four) They signal either that something has been omitted from quoted text, or that a speaker or writer has paused or trailed off in speech or thought.
Ellipsis (linguistics) (Wikipedia)
